# How to use catch with IO Handle

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to build a little program in Haskell in Leksah that will convert an .lhs file to an .hs file. But I can't get it to build without errors. Any help would be appreciated. I'm new to Haskell so forgive me if the answer is obvious, though I can't see it. Here is the code and error:

```
-- Converts .lhs (literary Haskell files) to .hs (plain Haskell files)
-- Keeps only the statements which are normally compiled, plus blank lines.

-- To use:
--    ghc --make lhs2hs.hs
-- to get an executable file lhs2hs.
-- Then
--    lhs2hs filename
-- will open filename.lhs and save the converted file in filename.hs

-- by Scot Drysdale on 7/28/07, based on SOE program on p. 241

module Main where
import System.IO
-- import System.IO.Error (catchIOError)
import Control.Exception (catch)
import System.Environment   -- to allow getArgs

-- Opens a file, given name and mode
openGivenFile :: String -> IOMode -> IO Handle
openGivenFile name mode
  =  catch (do handle <- openFile name mode
               return handle) 
            handler
            where
              handler :: IOError -> IO Handle 
              -- Next line does not match IO Handle
              handler ex = putStrLn $ "Caught exception: " ++ show ex
                                --   (\e -> error ("Cannot open " ++ name))

main = do args <- getArgs
          fromHandle <- openGivenFile (args !! 0 ++ ".lhs") ReadMode
          toHandle <- openGivenFile (args !! 0 ++ ".hs") WriteMode
          convertFile fromHandle toHandle
          hClose fromHandle
          hClose toHandle

-- Converts all the lines in a file
convertFile :: Handle -> Handle -> IO ()
convertFile fromHandle toHandle
  = catch (do line <- hGetLine fromHandle
              case line of
                          ('>' : ' ' : rest) -> hPutStrLn toHandle rest
                          ('>' : rest)       -> hPutStrLn toHandle rest
                          ('\n' : rest)      -> hPutStrLn toHandle line
                          ('\r' : rest)      -> hPutStrLn toHandle line 
                          _                  -> return ()
              convertFile fromHandle toHandle)
              handler
              where
               handler :: IOError -> IO ()
               handler ex = putStrLn $ "Caught exception: " ++ show ex
```

Error is :

```
 src\Main.hs:27:28-69:
    Couldn't match type `()' with `Handle'
    Expected type: IO Handle
      Actual type: IO ()
    In the expression: putStrLn $ "Caught exception: " ++ show ex
    In an equation for `handler':
        handler ex = putStrLn $ "Caught exception: " ++ show ex
    In an equation for `openGivenFile':
        openGivenFile name mode
          = catch
              (do { handle <- openFile name mode;
                    return handle })
              handler
          where
              handler :: IOError -> IO Handle
              handler ex = putStrLn $ "Caught exception: " ++ show ex
```

Comment: `putStrLn` returns `IO ()`. I don't know why you'd expect it to work. If you expect a possibility of failure return `IO (Maybe Handle)` - add `Just` to the main path and `return Nothing` to your handler

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was IO but I didn't know how to adress it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A signature such as

```
openGivenFile :: String -> IOMode -> IO Handle
```

states that `openGivenFile` returns an `Handle`, unless it throws an exception.

If you decide to catch `IOError`s inside that, that's fine by itself, but you need some way to come up with an `Handle` in every case -- which is impossible.

So, either you need to let the exception flow out if it, or you need to change the signature so that you no longer promise an `Handle` but something weaker. E.g.

```
openGivenFile :: String -> IOMode -> IO (Either IOError Handle)
openGivenFile name mode
  =  catch (do handle <- openFile name mode
               return (Right handle)) 
            handler
            where
              handler :: IOError -> IO (Either IOError Handle)
              handler ex = do
                 -- since we are returning the error,
                 -- printing it may be a bad design now
                 putStrLn $ "Caught exception: " ++ show ex
                 return (Left ex)
```

After some cleanup:

```
openGivenFile :: String -> IOMode -> IO (Either IOError Handle)
openGivenFile name mode = (Right <$> openFile name mode) `catch` handler
   where handler :: IOError -> IO (Either IOError Handle)
         handler = return . Left
```

Even this would work:

```
openGivenFile :: String -> IOMode -> IO (Either IOError Handle)
openGivenFile name mode =
   (Right <$> openFile name mode) `catch` (return . Left)
```

but the exception being catched is a now a bit hidden inside the type signature of the whole function. Since this is an one-liner, it should be clear enough, but I'd prefer the previous alternative in general since it document the intent of catching `IOError` better.

Comment: I used the first example you gave and it worked. Thanks. But then the function convertFIle didn't recognize the variables fromHandle and toHandle. I changed the function declaration to "convertFile :: (Either IOError Handle) -> (Either IOError Handle) -> IO ()" and the variables are recognized, but now hGetLine fails with the new variable type (different from the expected type Handle). Any ideas?

Comment: If the result is a `Left  ioError`, you should stop what you are doing and handle it. It makes little sense to call `convertFile` unless you have two actual `Handles`. The point is -- the code above just shift exceptions into the `Either` type. You can forward that, thus postponing the error handling, as much as you want. But there will be some point in your program where you will want to check what's inside these `Either`s: if it's a `Left`, stop, if it's a `Right`, take the handle and continue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the program to work. Thanks Chi. I marked your answer as the answer. Here is the final code:

Edit: ammended code for End-of-File check so as not to get exception in normal run.

```
-- Converts .lhs (literary Haskell files) to .hs (plain Haskell files)
-- Keeps only the statements which are normally compiled, plus blank lines.

-- To use:
--    ghc --make lhs2hs.hs
-- to get an executable file lhs2hs.
-- Then
--    lhs2hs filename
-- will open filename.lhs and save the converted file in filename.hs

-- by Scot Drysdale on 7/28/07, based on SOE program on p. 241

module Main where
import System.IO
import System.IO.Error
import Control.Exception (catch)
import System.Environment   -- to allow getArgs

-- Opens a file, given name and mode
openGivenFile :: String -> IOMode -> IO (Either IOError Handle)
openGivenFile name mode
  = catch (do handle <- openFile name mode
              return (Right handle))
           handler
           where
             handler :: IOError -> IO (Either IOError Handle)
             handler ex = do
                 -- since we are returning the error,
                 -- printing it may be a bad design now
                putStrLn $ "Caught exception: " ++ show ex
                return (Left ex)

main = do args <- getArgs
          (Right fromHandle) <- openGivenFile (args !! 0 ++ ".lhs") ReadMode
          (Right toHandle) <- openGivenFile (args !! 0 ++ ".hs") WriteMode
        --  (Right fromHandle) <- openGivenFile (head args) ReadMode
        --  (Right toHandle) <- openGivenFile (head args) WriteMode
          convertFile fromHandle toHandle
          hClose fromHandle
          hClose toHandle

-- Converts all the lines in a file
convertFile :: Handle -> Handle -> IO ()
convertFile fromHandle toHandle
  = catch ( do ineof <- hIsEOF fromHandle
               if ineof
                  then return ()
                  else do line <- hGetLine fromHandle
                          case line of
                            ('>' : ' ' : rest) -> hPutStrLn toHandle rest
                            ('>' : rest)       -> hPutStrLn toHandle rest
                            ('\n' : rest)      -> hPutStrLn toHandle line
                            ('\r' : rest)      -> hPutStrLn toHandle line
                            _                  -> return ()
                          convertFile fromHandle toHandle)
           handler
           where
             handler :: IOError -> IO ()
             handler ex = putStrLn $ "Caught exception: " ++ show ex
```